# expected '15 is prime' to deeply equal [ 3, 5 ]

Tags: javascript

Есть [задача на CodeWars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/544aed4c4a30184e960010f4/train/javascript), нужно найти все делители числа и вернуть их, если число простое, то нужно вернуть `"n is prime"`.

```
divisors(12); // should return [2,3,4,6]
divisors(25); // should return [5]
divisors(13); // should return "13 is prime"
```

Попробовал так:

```
function divisors(integer) {
  const arr = []
  for (let i = 2; i < integer; i++) {
    if (integer % i == 0) {
      arr.push(i)
     } if(arr.length == 0) {
       return integer + ' is prime'
     }
  }
  return arr
}
```

Но в тестах получил:

> expected '15 is prime' to deeply equal [ 3, 5 ]

Comment: Проверка длины массива должна быть после цикла.

Answer (score 1):

```
function divisors(integer) {
  const arr = []
  for (let i = 2; i < integer; i++) {
    if (integer % i == 0) {
      arr.push(i)
     }
  }
   if(arr.length == 0) {
       return integer + ' is prime'
     }
  return arr
}
```

По совету [@Alexey Ten](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1562351/expected-15-is-prime-to-deeply-equal-3-5/1562353#comment2814040_1562351)
, решил задачу.